# android dagger cannot provide injection

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger

I want to include dagger in my android app.
I have two classes *FakeServiceConnector*, *NetServiceConnector* which implements *ServiceConnector* interface

So I put code in my activity

```
@Inject
ServiceConnector serviceConnector;
```

Abd I create provider for resolving dependencies

```
@Module
public class ServiceConnectorProvider {

 @Provides
 @Singleton
 public ServiceConnector provideServiceConnector()
 {
    return new FakeServiceConnector();
 }
}
```

But when I push button serviceConnector is null.
So my questions are:

1) I include in my libs only dagger-1.1.0.jar and java.inject.jar  Is it enough for proper dagger installation?

2) Do I need write more code than I wrote for dagger such as creating Android

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you need to write more code for make it working.

First you have to specify in module which class you want to inject:

```
@Module(
    injects = YourClass.class
)
```

After you have to make injections:

```
ObjectGraph objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new ServiceConnectorProvider());
YourClass yourClassObject = objectGraph.get(YourClass.class);
```

or:

```
ObjectGraph objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new ServiceConnectorProvider());
YourClass yourClassObject = new YourClass(...);
objectGraph.inject(yourClassObject);
```

Take a look on the basic examples [here](http://square.github.io/dagger/) or [here](https://github.com/square/dagger/tree/master/examples) or search [GitHub](https://github.com/) for more of them.